# How to add column 1 of second csv file under the column 1 of the first csv file using R

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I have multiple csv files. I want to place the content of all the column ones from all the csv files in one column. I also want do not want specific number of rows to be included in this.

Example
file1.csv

```
         Column1 Column2
            A       1  
            B       2
            C       3
            D       4
            E       5
```

file2.csv

```
         Column1 Column2
           F         6
           G         7
           H         8
           I         9
           J         10
```

Result
Result.csv

```
        Column1  Column2
          C          3
          D          4
          E          5
          H          8
          I          9
          J          10
```

My code:

```
   temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
   myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim,nrow=4292,skip=1472,sep=",")
   nana<-do.call(rbind,myfiles)
   write.table(nana,"result_polmeans.csv",sep=",")
```

This code produces 2 columns per each csv file. The error stems from do.call function 
       Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
       names do not match previous names

Comment: Try, `do.call(rbind,myfiles)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `Reduce` after creating `myfiles` to solve this problem

```
all.data <- Reduce(function(x,y) rbind(x, y), myfiles)
```

It will take the `myfiles` list and rbind all of it's elements together, leaving you with a single data frame to pass into `write.table`

Answer (score 3):

Data frames can be appended with "row-bind" syntax like `rbind(df1,df2,df3,...)`.

If you have a list of data frames, `do.call` can be used to bind them:

```
do.call(rbind,myfiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
   new.data <- NULL

   for(i in temp) { 
                   in.data <- read.table(i,skip=1472,sep=",")
                   new.data <- rbind(new.data, in.data)
                }

   write.table(new.data,"result_polmeans.csv",sep=",")
```